# Cache refresh on db changes

Tags: java

How I can refresh my cache automatically whenever the DB update happen.

I am using Spring framework to build the application.

I have created the project using spring boot.I am new to spring cache mechanism.

Comment: Please explain yourself more clearly

Comment: You have encountered the [second hard thing](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) in computer science - don't expect a lazy question on Stackoverflow to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that the cache has the same content of the db you have two possibilities:

- update your db only via your program. This ensure that you know when an update happens and so you can update the cache at the same time
- use a trigger on the db to inform your program that an update has happened.

For the second solution every database has a different method to handle triggers. If possible a possible solution is to expose from your program a rest interface and call the rest interface from the trigger.

---

If having a cache not aligned with the db, a solution is to make polling on the db refreshing periodically your cache.